# MySql update timestamp curruption

Tags: mysql

I have a strange result when updating a table that includes a timestamp, does anyone know why this happens and is there another solution? My code is

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

create temporary table _peters
(
    order_time TIMESTAMP,
    pickup_time TIMESTAMP,
    item_count INT DEFAULT 0
);

insert _peters (order_time, pickup_time)
      select '2018-10-20T09:00:00.000', '2018-10-20T09:00:00.000'
union select '2018-10-20T10:00:00.000', '2018-10-20T10:00:00.000'
union select '2018-10-20T11:00:00.000', '2018-10-20T11:00:00.000';

update _peters p,
(
    select '2018-10-20T10:00:00.000' as order_time,
           '2018-10-20T10:00:00.000' as pickup_time,
           10 as item_count
) z
set p.item_count = z.item_count, p.pickup_time = z.pickup_time
where p.order_time = z.order_time
and p.pickup_time = z.pickup_time;

select * from _peters;
drop temporary table _peters;
```

Note the

> set p.item_count = z.item_count, p.pickup_time = z.pickup_time

Without the "p.pickup_time = z.pickup_time" the destination timestamp gets corrupted, as can be seen in these results.

[Result of select * from _peters;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5UwI.jpg)

Any ideas anyone - or this a bug? Thank you.

Comment: Does that field have an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` set as `DEFAULT` ?   It would help to have the `CREATE` statement for the exact schema you are using btw.

Comment: @Zak - The entire create statement is in the sample code, and I do not have an ON UPDATE. However your suggestion that it is an automatic update looks as though you might be on the right track.

Comment: @Zak - Actually I just ran the code again and it looks as though you are 100% correct. Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening when I do not have any ON-UPDATE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have your field set as `TIMESTAMP` -- If you used `DATETIME`, you can define any date/time and it shouldn't get overwritten.  `TIMESTAMP` defaults to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
create temporary table _peters
(
    order_time DATETIME,
    pickup_time DATETIME,
    item_count INT DEFAULT 0
);
```

Comment: thanks for that, will do. I am curious though; why would MySQL do that when the column has a value and there is no ON UPDATE (I can understand it would do that if the column was null/unitialised, but it has a value)?

Comment: Sorry - I need to RTFM - "explicit_defaults_for_timestamp"

Comment: Correct -- Even though it's not "defined" -- It's still a default.